# Display submenu on hover and keep it there

Tags: jquery, css

When I hover over a menu item, the background changes colour and also a submenu gets displayed. How to get the submenu to continue to display and the changes background to remain when I move the mouse form the menu item onto the submenu?

My html

```
<div class="shoplink"><a>Online Shop</a></div>
<div id="shop-menu">
            <ul>
                <li>Food</li>
                <li>Home & Living</li>
                <li>Personal Assistance</li>
                <li>Kids</li>
                <li>Musical Instruments</li>
                <li>Beauty & Wellbeing</li>
                <li>Outdoor</li>
                <li>Office & Stationery</li>
                <li>Cards & Gift Paper</li>
                <li><b>Browse All</b></li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- #shop-menu -->
```

My JS so far....

```
$('#shop-menu').hide();
$('.shoplink').live('hover', function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('activeitem');
    $('#shop-menu').toggle();
});
```

So I can display the shop-menu when I hover over .sublink. I just keep it there when I move the mouse from .shoplink onto the #shop-menu to select an item.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your toogles are displaying and hiding the menu... try:

```
$('#shop-menu').hide();
$('.shoplink').live('hover', function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('activeitem');
    $('#shop-menu').show();
});
```

In order to change it back, you can check @Madhu Rox answer and do like that:

```
$('#shop-menu').live('mouseleave', function(e) {
    $('.shoplink').removeClass('activeitem');
    $('#shop-menu').hide();
});
```

You could also `unbind` the hover event like `$(this).unbind('hover');`, but then, if another action in the page closes it and you'd want to reopen, you'd have to rebind the hover event.

Comment: If mouse is moving off the newly displayed list, how do I get the #shop-menu and .shoplink to change back to original form when mouse leaves the #shop-menu div?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the dropdown inside the menu item

```
<div class="shoplink">
     <a>Online Shop</a>
     <div id="shop-menu">
            <ul>
                <li>Food</li>
                <li>Home & Living</li>
                <li>Personal Assistance</li>
                <li>Kids</li>
                <li>Musical Instruments</li>
                <li>Beauty & Wellbeing</li>
                <li>Outdoor</li>
                <li>Office & Stationery</li>
                <li>Cards & Gift Paper</li>
                <li><b>Browse All</b></li>
            </ul>
     </div> <!-- #shop-menu -->
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cU629/

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML to wrap entire sub menu and the menu item with the `<div class="shoplink">`

Your code will be like

```
<div class="shoplink">
  menu item
    sub menu
</div>
```

or as previous answer, update your java script to

```
$('#shop-menu').hide();
$('.shoplink').live('hover', function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('activeitem');
    $('#shop-menu').show();
});
```

and also add the following code after that

```
$('#shop-menu').live('mouseleave', function(e) {
    $('.shoplink').removeClass('activeitem');
    $('#shop-menu').hide();
});
```